# Approximating of sine and the remainder

Tags: c++, c, math

The goal of the exercise is evaluating `sin` using the Maclaurin series formula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double factorial(int n);

int main(void) {

    double x, p, r;
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter a positive double number and a non - negative integer : \n");
    scanf("%lf%d", &x, &n);

    if (x <= 0) {
        printf("Error: first argument must be a positive double.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Error: second argument must be a non - negative integer.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        p += pow(-1, i) / factorial(2 * i + 1) * pow(x, 2 * i + 1);
    }

    r = fabs(sin(x) - p);

    printf("The %d-th order Maclaurin polynomial function at x=%f is %f, with an error approximation of %f.\n", n, x, p, r);



    getch();
    return 0;
}

double factorial(int n)
{
    int i;
    long result = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        result *= i;

    return result;
}
```

I get weird result for the input "12 16". Why?

Comment: You need to do a bit of algebra on the series to remove the overflows.

Comment: a) What´s this weird result? b) I didn´t read a single character of your code yet, but read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Enter a positive double number and a non - negative integer :
12 16
The 16-th order Maclaurin polynomial function at x=12.000000 is -194882636741915
770000000000.000000, with an error approximation of 194882636741915770000000000.
000000.

Comment: your `printf` uses `%f` instead of `%lf`.

Comment: @Wimmel, I've understood that's totally fine using `%f` for printing `double`.

Comment: The MacLaurin series is a decent small-number approximation of the sine function. _Small number!_ Try `0.01 10`, for example.

Comment: @DavidK, Could you explain further the behavior of the program for `0.01 10`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three issues here.

- As Mukit Chowdhury answered, longs can't hold large factorials. However, as GregS commented, there should be no problem with 16!. You should expect strange results when you use a long to hold 21! or greater, but **you don't need to change your factorial function for this input**. You probably should use something like the following instead, though:

  ```
  double factorial(int n)
  {
      int i;
      double result = 1;
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
          result *= i;
      return result;
  }
  ```
- On the input "12 16", your code claims to be calculating the 16th order Maclaurin polynomial, but it computes the 33rd order Maclaurin polynomial instead. The 16th order polynomial has terms up to -x^15/15! + 0x^16. One way to fix this is to correct the for loop as follows:

  ```
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i+=2)
  {
      p += pow(-1, (i-1)/2) / factorial(i) * pow(x, i);
  }
  ```

  So, your code is running into problems with the factorial, but only because you are calculating extra terms. If you calculate the terms up to -x^15/15!, you should be able to calculate the value of the polynomial correctly.
- The actual value of the 16th order Maclaurin polynomial at 12 is -4306.756... which might not be what you expect, and this is probably part of the point of the exercise. To get an accurate approximation, you should expect that you will need the last term to be small, so you need n! to exceed x^n. By Stirling's approximation, n! ~ (n/e)^n, so you want n > e*x, where e = 2.71828..., so n>=33. At that point, the error is 0.005, and increasing n by c decreases the size of the error by about a factor of e^c.
- You should expect large errors in double precision arithmetic when you subtract large numbers on the way to producing a small final result. This probably isn't an issue here, since the largest terms are only about 2^14 in magnitude. You still get enough precision that you won't notice that you can't get very close to sin(12) by adding more terms.

Comment: Can you explain the claim: "On the input "12 16", your code claims to be calculating the 16th order Maclaurin polynomial, but it computes the 33rd order Maclaurin polynomial instead"?

Comment: As I see it, it's just a semantic change (what you've done at the code of the loop).

Answer (score 3):

The quotient between two terms of the MacLauring or Taylor series for the sine is

```
-x*x/(2*k*(2k+1))
```

This can be gainfully exploited to avoid all powers and factorials and their overflows.

```
mxx = -x*x;
term = mxx / 6;
sum = 1+term;
k=2;
while( not good enough )
    term = term*mxx/(2*k*(2*k+1));
    sum = sum + term;
    k = k+1;

return sum*x
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things that I would do differently here.

I'm a bit biased from having to write numerical software that not only gets correct results but gets them quickly, but I see a lot of wasted computation here. Consider two consecutive non-zero terms of the series, for example
(x^13)/(13!) and -(x^15)/(15!). If you already know the value of
(x^13)/(13!), how much more computation do you need to do to get -(x^15)/(15!)?
The answer is, a lot less than it took to compute (x^13)/(13!)
in the first place. If you slavishly follow the usual formula
for the MacLaurin series and recompute the factorial for each new term,
in order to get 15! you will repeat all the calculations you already did
for 13!, and then perform just two new multiplications.
To compute this series efficiently without wasted computation and without
introducing unnecessarily large numbers (and all the possible problems
they can cause, even if you use floating-point for everything), 
just look at the ratio between one non-zero term
and the next. It's easy to compute and doesn't involve dragging in
the `pow` function.
A good algorithm will let you easily increase the number of terms until the last
term is on the order of precision of your floating-point numbers,
provided you use a reasonable input value of x.
(There's no need for x to be greater than 2*pi, or for that matter really
no good reason to set x greater than pi/2, since the sine of any larger
value of x can be found from the values of sine for input in that range.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it in Java (easy to convert to C++):

```
package math;

/**
 * Sine using Maclauren series
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445615/approximating-of-sine-and-the-remainder
 * @since 4/4/2015 8:37 PM
 */
public class Sine {

    private static final double TWO_PI = 2.0*Math.PI;
    private static final int numPoints = 21;
    private static final int numTerms = 21;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = -Math.PI;
        double dx = 2.0*Math.PI/(numPoints-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("# terms: %d angle (radians) %10.6f sine: %15.10f", numTerms, x, sine(x, numTerms)));
            x += dx;
        }
    }

    public static double sine(double radians, int numTerms) {
        double value = 0.0;
        // Start by making sure the angle -pi/2 <= x <= +pi/2
        double x = normalizeAngle(radians);
        double term = x;
        for (int n = 3; n < numTerms; n += 2) {
            value += term;
            term *= -x*x/n/(n-1);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static double normalizeAngle(double radians) {
        return radians - TWO_PI*Math.floor((radians+Math.PI)/TWO_PI);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
java math.Sine
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -3.141593 sine:   -0.0000000224
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -2.827433 sine:   -0.3090169974
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -2.513274 sine:   -0.5877852526
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -2.199115 sine:   -0.8090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -1.884956 sine:   -0.9510565163
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -1.570796 sine:   -1.0000000000
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -1.256637 sine:   -0.9510565163
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -0.942478 sine:   -0.8090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -0.628319 sine:   -0.5877852523
# terms: 21 angle (radians)  -0.314159 sine:   -0.3090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   0.000000 sine:    0.0000000000
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   0.314159 sine:    0.3090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   0.628319 sine:    0.5877852523
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   0.942478 sine:    0.8090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   1.256637 sine:    0.9510565163
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   1.570796 sine:    1.0000000000
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   1.884956 sine:    0.9510565163
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   2.199115 sine:    0.8090169944
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   2.513274 sine:    0.5877852526
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   2.827433 sine:    0.3090169974
# terms: 21 angle (radians)   3.141593 sine:   -0.0000000224

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your factorial() is returning a **long** whereas it's return type is **double**.

And the most important one is, **long** can not contain **16!**. Which **double** can.

Comment: You right. What a miserable mistake. Can you tell me what actually happened "behind the scenes"?

Comment: I think, it is just like as, you are calling a man named Mike as Peter. What will Mike do? He will not response you. Here, result has to return a double value, but it has not that ability. So a garbage value is returned.

Comment: @Elimination Why don't you test it? Feed your function numbers, and check the output against what you expect. It isn't at all clear that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is just that, as said above, 16! does not fit in `long`. Therefore it is _already_ a garbage value long before the return. This garbage value is then faithfully cast from `long` to `double`, but by then it's too late.

Comment: I wonder why everybody keep claiming that 16! doesn't fit into a long? On most platforms I've used a long is 64 bits, into which 16! fits comfortably

Comment: While 16! does fit into a long (under 2^45), 33! does not (over 2^122), and this calculation is going up to the x^33/33! term.

Comment: @GregS On most platforms I've used a long was 32 bits, but most platforms I've used are obsolete. In this case actually this is all kind of beside the point because the program has no need to (and should not) depend on even 64-bit integers.